# Receiving Android SMS

Tags: java, android, sms

I have been trying so many different things to get this demo running but i couldn't manage to make it run properly..

This is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.messagekeeper"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="9" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.messagekeeper.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <receiver android:name=".SmsReciever"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver> 

</application>

</manifest>
```

This is my MainActivity class (Done nothing with it):

```
package com.example.messagekeeper;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And This is the SmsReciever class:

```
package com.example.messagekeeper;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

class SmsReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    Object[] pdus=(Object[])intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
    SmsMessage shortMessage=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);

        Log.d("SMSReceiver","SMS message sender: "+
               shortMessage.getOriginatingAddress());
        Log.d("SMSReceiver","SMS message text: "+
               shortMessage.getDisplayMessageBody());


  }

}
```

When i get a message, i want it to see it on my app. In this situation, i mean when i use this codes and run my app on emulator, and send a message from one emulator to another, my app crashes and i get this error: http://puu.sh/1yZub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've copied your code exactly as it stands, you might be just missing the `public` keyword at the beginning.

Change `class SmsReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{`

to `public class SmsReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{`

Comment: I have been trying to make this app for an 3.5 hours now and i really facepalmed my ownself when i tried your solution and its worked. I don't really know how to thank you. You probably saved my 2-3 hours by answering this question. Thank you so much.